# How replicate () an apply process with random function inside in r?

Tags: r, random, apply, replicate

I want to run several times (B times, suppose) an apply that gives me a data.frame based on a random data generated by another function. I want to do that without a for-loop (I've tried using for and it works but I want to do it with replicate() or some shorter method)

This what I want:

```
results=c()
for(i in 1:B) {
 results=cbind(results, lapply(random.data, function (x) main.function(x))
```

and it gives me a data.frame of 10xB, for example and where `random.data` is a list of data.frames generated by a random function and `main.function(x)` is a function that only admits a data.frame (no lists).

This is what I've tried:

```
results=sapply(random.data, function(x) main.function(x)) %>% replicate(B,.)
```

This runs but it doesn't do what I want, it gives a data.frame of 10xB but all columns are the same.

Comment: Something like: `replicate(B, my.function(random.data))` where `my.function` does everything.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. 
It seems like `%>%` doesn't get along with random processes.

This works:

```
results=replicate(B,sapply(random.data, function(x) main.function(x)))
```

This doesn't work:

```
results=sapply(random.data, function(x) main.function(x)) %>% replicate(B,.)
```